# Is the List interface a leaky abstraction?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

If I have a variable containing a `List` it could contain objects of a lot of different types e.g. `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. The difference between a `LinkedList` and an `ArrayList` is pretty big. The big O behavior of the methods differs greatly. For example sorting the `List` and then using it to do binary searches is perfectly ok for an `ArrayList` but would not make sense with a `LinkedList`.

Comment: What does "the big O" mean ?

Comment: @user61852 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 24):

I wouldn't say so.

A leaky abstraction is one that forces you to deal with implementation details that it's supposed to abstract away. But performance *always* differs between implementations, so if you count that as leaking, then there are no non-leaking abstractions.

If something is declared as `List` without further documentation, it should be understood that there are simply no guarantees about performance, and if you're going to do anything performance-sensitive with it, you should make a copy and work with that.

Also, don't forget that there's an even more general interface that is often sufficient in functionality and does not tempt you to make as many assumptions about performance: `Collection`.

Comment: There is an even more general interface that is often sufficient in functionality:  `Iterable`.

Comment: Performance differences between the different implementations are expected. E.g. there are differences between Vector and ArrayList, but a get operation on a LinkedList just seems strange.

Answer (score 17):

[All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) That said, I'm not really sure it applies here. :-)

Abstractions are concerned with behaviour. Unless the behaviour specifies particular performance (which Java's `List` does not) it's an implementation detail - i.e. irrelevant.

Java doesn't allow you to specify minimum performance for interfaces outside of documentation, and I'm not aware of any languages which do - it would be incredibly hard (impossible?) for the compiler to verify. I can see a couple of options if performance is a concern:

1. Document it in the class/interface the list instance will belong to.
2. Create a new interface - e.g. `BinarySearchPerformantList` (yuck!) - which specifies the performance requirements of the various methods.

Option 2 is probably the better abstraction, but comes with extra overhead.

Comment: +1.  Technically yes, a [List is a leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), but then so is Object for hiding complexity related to using `equals` to compare objects.

Comment: @Neil I think it's debatable... Since the abstraction doesn't mention performance I don't think it's failing in this case (as I've argued). I'd say that if you're thinking about performance you need a different/narrower abstraction. Will edit to mention that.

Comment: It depends on what you're hiding I suppose.  Is complexity in the usage or is it in its memory usage and implementation?  Because if it is an abstract class, one or more of these complexities is getting hidden in one way or another.

Comment: I played around many years back implementing a variation of Option 2 using marker interfaces like `LinearSpace` and `LogarithmicTime` and then declaring classes like `public class BinarySearch : ISearchStrategy<T>, LogarithmicTime`.  Other classes could take parameters like `public T find<T, S>(IList<T> list, S strategy) where S : ISearchStrategy<T>, LogarithmicTime { }` to enforce performance constraints.

Comment: If we're going by the Joel Spolsky article, I think it is "to some degree, leaky". See the following quote from the article: "If you were curt with the system administrators in your company and they punished you by plugging you into an overloaded hub, only some of your IP packets will get through, and TCP will work, but everything will be really slow" I think this applies

Comment: @AmishProgrammer Joel is talking about usable practical abstractions, I'm talking about purely theoretical ones. If you want my List operations to work in finite time and a finite memory space, you'd better specify it! :)

Comment: @Lucas I'm guessing it didn't pan out too well? I can see that approach leading to having a huge number of interfaces...

Comment: @Baqueta It wasn't too bad at first.  The real problem was figuring out how to mark algorithms like a simple quicksort that have expected O(n log n) time, but worst case O(n^2).  I don't know C++ that well, but you'd probably need something like meta-template programming to create parametrized `BigO<T>`, `BigTheta<T>`, `LittleO<T>`, and `BigOmega<T>` types and use those to fully characterize time and space complexity. e.g. something like `NaiveQuickSort : BigTheta<NLogN>, BigOmega<Quadratic, AlmostNever>,  BigO<NLogN>`

Comment: @Baqueta Not to mention an algorithm like Coppersmith–Winograd Matrix Multiplication that is characterized by `O(n^2.3727)`.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, there is a [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface which is defined as a list with generally constant random access time (O(1) get, put etc.). If you feel that your module requires a list with those performance characteristics, consider using `RandomAccess` instead of `List`. If you don't feel the need to make that change (and few do), then perhaps List is not so leaky.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, a List is a leaky abstraction. The STL uses the idea of [concepts](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html) to model this specific problem. To use your example, an `ArrayList` models a [Random Access Iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html) while a LinkedList models a [Forward Iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html). Different concepts have different performance requirements, which make them appropriate for different [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).